# Redundant aggregate vs redundant GROUP BY?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a query that joins two tables by a column that happens to be a primary key for one of those tables. I also `GROUP BY` the same column. Now I need to return some columns from the table with the primary key. In MySQL I could just add those to the select statement and not worry a thing, but in SQL Server I have to either add them to `GROUP BY` or enclose in an aggregate function (like `MAX`). Logically both are redundant as the primary key ensures that the columns which I want to fetch will have the same value across the group. The question is which solution is better (using aggregate function or putting them in `GROUP BY`)?

I tested both variants and they appear to have the same query cost. The execution plans are nearly identical, but the variant with aggregate function (`MAX`) appears to be slightly faster. However using aggregate functions puts some restrictions on types used and forces me to convert the types of some columns around needlessly (I'm looking at you `bit` column). Note, I actually do need the results to match certain types.

P.S. I could also move the columns which actually need to be grouped to a subquery and put it in the `FROM` section to avoid using aggregate functions or `GROUP BY` on columns which don't need it. However, my gut is telling me it's not going to make it faster (gotta test it).

---

Yet again I'm proven that when it comes to SQL there are no answers that are always correct. The answer in my case was not to use either of the two solutions. My gut was wrong and putting the tables\columns that do need to be grouped to a subquery and than joining them with the rest was the way to go (execution time was even shorter). However in another query this solution could make things worse.

So rather than find an answer to redundant `GROUP BY` vs redundant aggregate, I found out that it is actually a redundant `GROUP BY` vs redundant aggregate vs a subquery with a non-redundant `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I solved my particular problem myself, but I need to add some sample code to the question to make it more useful to others (or write it as an answer).

Comment: Yes, if you have an answer, you ought to post it *as* an answer. Questions should contain the problem, Answers should contain solution(s), and the answer that worked for you should be marked as accepted (so that we know you're no longer looking for answers). It's explicitly called out in the StackOverflow help that it's perfectly fine for you to write an answer to your own question and accept it (although I think there are some enforced time delays between posting and accepting).